# Transact SQL, how can I take varchar type, convert to int, add one, convert back to string, then store?

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AmendInsertDuplicateFields] (@ReportID varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewReportID VARCHAR(50)
    SET @NewReportID = NEWID()

    INSERT INTO [MVCOmar].[dbo].[PrideMVCCollisionBegin]
           ([ReportID], [LocalIncidentNum], [version], [MTOReferenceNo], [Submitted]) 
       SELECT 
          @NewReportID, [LocalIncidentNum], [version], [MTOReferenceNo], [Submitted] 
       FROM 
          [MVCOmar].[dbo].[PrideMVCCollisionBegin] 
       WHERE 
          [ReportID] = @ReportID;
```

I would like to take the result that I get for `version`, convert it from string to int type, add one, convert back to string, and store it.

I acknowledge that version should be `int` and not string type. I also acknowledge that an even better method of accomplishing this would be to set properties to increment by one.

I can't do either of those option for the time being because my priorities are different right now, I am time limited, the code is very old, and written by numerous people which carried poor coding habits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need to convert it, run this, there will be an implicit conversion

```
SELECT '1' + 1
```

That returns 2

In your case you can just do `[version] + 1`

Comment: WOW! didn't know it was smart enough to be able to do that.

Comment: Agreed, I didn't realize it would perform the implicit conversion in *both* directions. Much nicer solution. :)

Comment: Just be aware that this won't work, so make sure you only have numbers in that column  `SELECT 'a' + 1`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this inline in your SELECT statement, using [the CONVERT function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```sql
INSERT INTO [MVCOmar].[dbo].[PrideMVCCollisionBegin] ([ReportID], [LocalIncidentNum], [version], [MTOReferenceNo], [Submitted]) 
SELECT @NewReportID, [LocalIncidentNum], 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, (CONVERT(INT, [version]) + 1)), 
       [MTOReferenceNo], [Submitted] 
FROM [MVCOmar].[dbo].[PrideMVCCollisionBegin] 
WHERE [ReportID]=@ReportID;
```

Comment: `if you use VARCHAR in the CONVERT function without specifying a length, it will assume a length of 1`  no,  it assumes a length of 30, 1 is only true for variables, this gives you all the numbers `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,123456789)`

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server supports CAST or CONVERT

```
CAST(col1 as int)

CONVERT(int,col1)
```